# REST Services For FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am Using FOSRestBundle For REST Services. Its Working fine . How can I Set the services for NewAction,UpdateAction,EditAction and DeleteAction For an Entity..? I didn't get any idea from the doc from github. Please Help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that isn't any rest crud generator. But you can read this links:

[FOSRestBundle, can't seem to figure out how to make JSON and HTML work all together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013213/fosrestbundle-cant-seem-to-figure-out-how-to-make-json-and-html-work-all-toget)

http://blog.dsyph3r.com/2011/10/connect-rest-with-symfony2.html